# Getting issue while installing @ethereum-alarm-clock/cli

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, nodes, sendtransaction, npm

Ran Command : `npm i -g @ethereum-alarm-clock/cli`
Issue received below :
I am able to install other packages though, Is there something i need to do?

[image]

while

```
npm i -g @ethereum-alarm-clock/lib
```

, I got

[image]

Comment: That package hasn't been updated for years. I wouldn't recommend using it. Check out https://www.gelato.network/ for example

Comment: @LauriPeltonen Is there a way where Payment(which can be random amount, lets say <100ETH) can be made from wallet A once he gives permission by a contract ?

Comment: Use Wrapper Eth (WETH), then you can play with allowances

Comment: Can you explain a little about this approach?

Comment: I understood WETH part, how can i play with allowances?

Comment: PLease post a new question or search for existing questions